# How to prove $\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{(r-1)π ^2}{\sqrt{1+(rπ )^4}}$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Using comparison test with the series $\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{1}{r}$.
The above series diverges. But how to show the comparison exactly?
$$1+(rπ)^4 < {((rπ)^2+1)}^2 ;
 \frac 1 {\sqrt{1+(rπ)^4}} > \frac 1 {(rπ)^2+1}$$
Help needed in proceeding further. Thank you

Comment: You could also check out the [Limit Comparison Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

Comment: Thank you, it is much more easier that way showing the limit tends to 1(finite nonzero).

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{r-1}{\sqrt{r^4\pi^4+1}}\ge\frac{r-1}{\sqrt{2r^4\pi^4}}=\frac{r-1}{r^2\pi^2\sqrt2}$$

Comment: Thank you for the logic I was searching for.